# Ruby traverse CSV row and bypass values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv

I have a spreadsheet that has 4 columns and I'm saving the result to the database. What I want is when it comes to a cell, `d`, that contains `"string"` bypass this row and save the next row and so on.

This is my model code

```
def self.assign_row(row)
  a, b, c, d = row
  @c = c.slice(1,4)
  Result.create(line: c, min: @c)
end

def self.import(file)
  CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|
    result = Result.assign_row(row)
  end
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CSV.foreach(file.path) do |row|

  # when it came to a cell 'd' that contain "string" bypass this row
  next if row['d'] =~ /string/

  result = Result.assign_row(row)
end
```

`next` will skip the rest of the current loop iteration; `=~` will check if regexp matches.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response
this is what i got after this
"
TypeError in ResultsController#import
no implicit conversion of String into Integer"

Comment: Oh, you likely use CSV without headers. Make it `row[3]` then.

Comment: TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer):
  app/models/result.rb:12:in `[]'
  app/models/result.rb:12:in `block in import'
  app/models/result.rb:11:in `import'
  app/controllers/results_controller.rb:4:in `import'

Comment: Huh? Unlike `row['d']`, there is no strings in `row[3]`, I don't know why you'd still be getting that error.

Comment: so what about deleting the whole row ?

Comment: `row['3']` is not the same as `row[3]`.

Comment: it was my mistake :)